# Macro to copy table cell content in the row

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-field, fieldcodes

I have have a Word table where the first column contains MERGEFIELD field codes.  I would like a macro button on each row to copy (to clipboard) the content of the cell (the MERGEFIELD) in that row.

Is that possible to do in an elegant way?

Comment: This question is a bit broad. You will need to show the code you already have.

Comment: Thanks. I have no code. I simply have a word document with a table in it, but I want to add a button in each row that copies the content of a particular cell in that row. I do not have experience with Macros or programming them. So thought someone here might know

Comment: So StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. You will need to start on your own and then come back with your code and a specific question to it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I get the point. Sorry. I will make an attempt, and get back once I stumble into issues.